# I am getting null pointer exception when i tried to download file from dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox

I dont how i am getting null pointer exception. I hacve uploaded the zip file to dropbox. But when I try to download it from dropbox, it is giving error.
I have used the below code:

```
public class DownloadZip extends AsyncTask {
private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

    File sdCardDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DoDoDo");
    if (!sdCardDir.exists()){
        sdCardDir.mkdir();
    }
    File file=new File(sdCardDir.getPath()+"/DatabaseZip.zip");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   DropboxAPI.DropboxFileInfo info;
    try {
       info= mDBApi.getFile("/DatabaseZip.zip", null, outputStream, null);//Getting exception here
        //Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The file's rev is: "
         //       + info.getMetadata().rev);
    } catch (DropboxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

I am calling the function from here:

```
private View.OnClickListener clickHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
    case R.id.importFromDropBtn:
                Log.d("import", "working");

                new DownloadZip().execute();
```

Comment: share your log cat message here

Comment: It seems like you never initialize mBDApi and therefore it is null and you can't call a method on it

Comment: share your log cat

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                  Process: com.example.anilcs.dodo, PID: 15569
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)

Comment: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI$DropboxFileInfo com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.getFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.io.OutputStream, com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.anilcs.dodo.DownloadZip.doInBackground(DownloadZip.java:37)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// And later in some initialization function:
AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
```

Use these lines to initialize the mDBApi object before using it in line

```
 info= mDBApi.getFile("/DatabaseZip.zip", null, outputStream, null);//Getting exception here
```

Replace APP_KEY, APP_SECRET these strings with your credentials

Comment: Thanks......Now I am not getting the exception. However, i could not download the zip file from the dropbox...

Comment: my log cat says like this:W/System.err: com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxUnlinkedException
W/System.err:     at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.assertAuthenticated(DropboxAPI.java:2717)
W/System.err:     at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.getFileStream(DropboxAPI.java:1533)
W/System.err:     at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.getFile(DropboxAPI.java:1497)
W/System.err:     at com.example.anilcs.dodo.DownloadZip.doInBackground(DownloadZip.java:44)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)

Comment: Paste your logcat output

Comment: W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/android


you need to follow and study this link thoroughly to implement this. It seem your are not calling 
mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MyActivity.this);
this line and auth is not completed.